# log4net:ERROR Exception while reading ConfigurationSettings. Check your .config file is well formed XML

Tags: c#, console-application, log4net

I am trying to implement log4net into my console application but I get a bunch of errors like

> log4net: Error exception while reading configurationSettings.

I googled and after checking many questions asked here at stackoverflow I posted this one. I know there is nothing wrong with my app.config file.

Here is my App.config file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />           
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
  </root>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

My LogHelper Class:

```
public class LogHelper
{
    public static log4net.ILog GetLogger([CallerFilePath]string filename = "")
    {
        return log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(filename);
    }
}
```

That is how I am using it in my main class Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]


namespace Shopping_List
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly log4net.ILog log = LogHelper.GetLogger(); //log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        private static void Main()
        {
            log.Info("This is info message");
            MyClass newClass = new MyClass();

            newClass.MyMethod();

            log.Info("This is info message");

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }

 
    
}
```

and here is my other class

```
public class MyClass
{

    //var itemList = new List<string>();
    List<String> itemList = new List<string>();
    int choices;

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        //var itemList = new List<string>();
        //int choices;

        while (true)
        {

            try
            {
                

                Console.WriteLine("Shopping list:\n1. Add to list\n2. Remove from list\n3. List the items on the shopping list\n4. Exit");
                choices = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n ");
                Console.WriteLine("You have Entered non-numeric value, you can only choose between 1 to 4");
                Console.WriteLine("\n ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n ");


                if (choices == 1)
                {
                    itemAdded();
                }

                else if (choices == 2)
                {
                    itemRemoved();
                }

                else if (choices == 3)
                {
                    readList();
                }

                else if (choices == 4)
                {
                    //break;
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("please enter valid choice!!!");
                }

        
           
        }


    }

    public void itemAdded()
    {

        //var itemList = new List<string>();

        

        Console.WriteLine("\nWhat would you like to add in the list?");
        string itemAdded = Console.ReadLine();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemAdded))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("you add nothing!!!");
        }
        else
        {
            itemList.Add(itemAdded);
            Console.WriteLine(itemAdded + " is added to the list");
        }
    }

    public void itemRemoved()
    {

        //var itemList = new List<string>();

        Console.WriteLine("\nWhat would you like to remove from the list?");
        string itemToRemove = Console.ReadLine();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemToRemove))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("you removed nothing");
        }
        else
        {
            bool isMatch = false;
            foreach (string item in itemList)
            {
                if (item == itemToRemove)
                {
                    isMatch = true;
                }
            }
            if (isMatch)//if ismatch is true
            {
                itemList.Remove(itemToRemove);
                Console.WriteLine(itemToRemove + " is successfully removed from your list");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Item is not in the list");
            }
        }

    }

    public void readList()
    {
        //var itemList = new List<string>();

        foreach (string item in itemList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }


}
```

I am not using log4net in myClass.

Comment: your `root` node is outside the `log4net` node, so default ConfigurationManager tries to read it, that structure is wrong.

Comment: ohh i though nothing wrong with my App.config file, Thanks @Cleptus

Comment: Remember always to index both your code and config files to spot that kind of errors. Added an answer I hope it will be useful to you and others

Comment: sure @Cleptus thanks for the valuable suggestion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your App.config file `log4net` section is badly configured. You closed the `log4net` node too soon.

It should be similar to this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
    </configSections>
    <log4net>
        <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />           
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <root>
            <level value="INFO"/>
            <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
        </root>
    </log4net>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```